# How to create a random memory matching game with as3

Tags: random, matching

I am trying to create a memory game based on shapes and colors. The graphical design is done but I can't seem to get the code right. This is what it is supposed to do:

1) there are 3 shapes and three colors for each shapes for a total of 9 possibilities;
2) They appear at random one after the other and the goal is to press right if the second shape is the same as the first one, or left if it isn't.
3) the rest I know how to code, but this first part.... I have no idea how to write it :(

I thought about making an array with all nine possibilities but how am I supposed to take one of the shapes at random from the array and make it appear on the stage, make the system remember it, select a second one at random again and than, compare it to the first?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in JAVA

```
String arr[]=new String[9];
    arr[0]="1";
    arr[1]="2";
    arr[2]="3";
    arr[3]="4";
    arr[4]="5";
    arr[5]="6";
    arr[6]="7";
    arr[7]="8";
    arr[8]="9";
    String firstVal=null;
    String secondVal=null;

    int index1=(int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
    int index2=(int) (Math.random() * arr.length);

    firstVal=arr[index1];
    secondVal=arr[index2];

    System.out.println(firstVal+" "+secondVal);
```